# What is the difference between TimeZoneInfo.Local and FindSystemTimeZoneById?

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, time, timezone

I know time and timezones is a difficult issue, yet I'm still confused by the following:

```
    Console.WriteLine("DST Test");
    var DT = DateTime.Now;
    TimeZoneInfo tzi = TimeZoneInfo.Local;
    bool DaylightSavingTime = tzi.IsDaylightSavingTime(DT);
    Console.WriteLine($"Time: {DT} DST: {DaylightSavingTime} TimeZone: {TimeZoneInfo.Local.DaylightName}");
    tzi = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("W. Europe Standard Time");
    DaylightSavingTime = tzi.IsDaylightSavingTime(DT);
    Console.WriteLine($"Time: {DT} DST: {DaylightSavingTime} TimeZone: {TimeZoneInfo.Local.DaylightName} ");
```

Output:

```
DST Test
Time: 31/05/2021 13:19:32 DST: False TimeZone: W. Europe Standard Time
Time: 31/05/2021 13:19:32 DST: True TimeZone: W. Europe Standard Time
```

So if I try to find out if the time is a Daylight Saving Time by calling the function from 'TimeZoneInfo.Local', the answer is false. But if I use the .FindSystemTimeZoneById() function, with the same time zone, I get a 'true', which is correct. How is this possible ?

Comment: Could you check the SupportsDaylightSavingTime Property of the TimeZoneInfo?

Comment: I can't reproduce this on a macOS system, with `Europe/London`. Might be something Windows-specific perhaps?

Comment: @TheTanic : In the first case : false, in the second: true. As expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the comments you approved, that the `SupportsDaylightSavingTime` of the `TimeZoneInfo`, which was received by: `TimeZoneInfo.Local` is `false`.

This depends on your machine settings. From the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timezoneinfo.supportsdaylightsavingtime?view=net-5.0#remarks):

> The value of the SupportsDaylightSavingTime property for the local time zone returned by the TimeZoneInfo.Local property reflects the setting of the Control Panel Date and Time application's checkbox that defines whether the system automatically adjusts for daylight saving time. If it is unchecked, or if no checkbox is displayed for a time zone, the value of this property is false.

This is the only obvious difference between the two methods you used.

Comment: OK, that sounds like the answer. So 'FindSystemTimeZoneById()' just creates a timezone info object that is independent of the local settings.

Comment: It seems like this. I dont appreciate the design behind it, but at least they added some informations about it in the documentation